# Flutter when I use dio get data, loading indicator will alway stop a few sec and can not click button in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, https, dio

This is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

class ListensScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  _ListensScreenState createState() => _ListensScreenState();
}

class _ListensScreenState extends State<ListensScreen> {
  Dio _dio = new Dio();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _dio.get("https://cnodejs.org/api/v1/topics"),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              Response response = snapshot.data;
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
              }
              return ListView(
                children: response.data["data"].map<Widget>((e) =>
                    ListTile(title: Text(e["title"]))
                ).toList(),
              );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: CircularProgressIndicator always stop a few sec(1~2sec)]

It doesn't seem to move much longer than GIF, and I can not click any button. It's very unfriendly to use

Android and Simulator do not have this problem. This problem only display when I test in my iPhone and download app in app store.

Flutter 1.12.13 and dio 3.0.9

I found this problem is on the server. When I use `https`, this problem will appear on the iOS. Android and Web is nothing wrong. Is iOS something different?

Thanks!

Comment: Issue Description and Steps
Please fill in the detailed description of the issue (full output of any stack trace, compiler error, ...) and the steps to reproduce the issue.
https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/703

This issue have ideas.

The problems come from Let's Encript in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this if your SSL web server (like nginx) is behind a firewall and has to use a http proxy to reach OCSP servers in order to implement OCSP Stapling.

https://github.com/virushuo/ocsp-proxy

Comment: Related issues: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41519  ; 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49392  ; 
https://jhuo.ca/post/ocsp-stapling-letsencrypt/  ; 
https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/703